# Show that $f(n)$ tends to $+\infty$ if $f$ is injective

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given that $f$ is an application from $\Bbb N \to  \Bbb N$  :

Show that the sequence $(f(n))_n$ tends to $+\infty$ if $f$ is injective. 
Since $f$ is injective I can see that every natural number has at most one antecedent by $f$ and since the set of antecedent is infinite the set of images by $f$ is also infinite. I have some trouble writing this correctly let alone find where to go from there to prove the question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - by "application" do you mean a function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: By definition of limit tending to $+\infty$, fix some $M>0$. Show that eventually $f(n) > M$ for all $n > N$ for some $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show, for all $M$ (without loss of generality, assume $M \in \Bbb{N}$), we can find an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
$$n > N \implies f(n) > M.$$
The set $\{1, 2, \ldots, M\}$ is a finite set. Note that
$$f^{-1}\{1, 2, \ldots, M\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^M f^{-1}\{n\},$$
where the right hand side is a finite union of singleton or empty sets (since $f$ is injective), which means the left hand side finite. Thus, we may define
$$N = \max f^{-1}\{1, 2, \ldots, M\}.$$
Hence,
$$n > N \implies n \notin f^{-1} \{1, 2, \ldots, M\} \implies f(n) \notin \{1, 2, \ldots, M\} \implies f(n) > M,$$
as required.

Comment: Im truly in awe, this proof looks so simple clean. Big thank you!